# How to fix: "Crawler reached the maxRequestsPerCrawl limit of 1 requests and will shut down soon"

Tags: node.js, cheerio, apify

**Cheerio crawler** is not crawling when I set `maxRequestPerCrawl` to 1.
Even when I set `maxRequestPerCrawl` to 10 or 100, after the 10th or 100th request nothing will be crawled again anymore. How can I fix that limitation?

I use a new instance of Cheerio for any single request, no parallel requests are necessary in my use cases.
However, it counts requests on a global basis, whether I use a new instance of Cheerio for every request or a shared instance.

Once the count of all requests reaches the value of `maxRequestPerCrawl`, it will deny all further requests. The only solution is to shutdown the full process and start it again.

Log:

```
INFO  CheerioCrawler: Starting the crawl
INFO  CheerioCrawler: Crawler reached the maxRequestsPerCrawl limit of 1 requests and will shut down soon. Requests that are in progress will be allowed to finish.
INFO  CheerioCrawler: Earlier, the crawler reached the maxRequestsPerCrawl limit of 1 requests and all requests that were in progress at that time have now finished. In total, the crawler processed 1 requests and will shut down.
INFO  CheerioCrawler: Crawl finished. Final request statistics: {"requestsFinished":0,"requestsFailed":0,"retryHistogram":[],"requestAvgFailedDurationMillis":null,"requestAvgFinishedDurationMillis":null,"requestsFinishedPerMinute":0,"requestsFailedPerMinute":0,"requestTotalDurationMillis":0,"requestsTotal":0,"crawlerRuntimeMillis":190}
```

My Code:

```
 const crawler = new CheerioCrawler({
      minConcurrency: 1,
      maxConcurrency: 1,

      //      proxyConfiguration: {},

      // On error, retry each page at most once.
      maxRequestRetries: 1,

      // Increase the timeout for processing of each page.
      requestHandlerTimeoutSecs: 30,

      // Limit to 10 requests per one crawl
      maxRequestsPerCrawl: 1,

     async requestHandler({ request, $, proxyInfo }) {
            // ...
     }
  )}

    await crawler.run([url]);
    await crawler.teardown();
```

What am I missing here to be able to run the crawler even with thousands of requests in a row?

Comment: Just change maxRequestsPerCrawl to a higher number? It sounds like it's doing what it's supposed to.